# Steps for setting up Tom Cat and Apache for multiple users

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tomcat

My goal is to use mod_userdir to individually allow users to put java webapps in their user's public_html folder.

I have Apache, mod_userdir, and Tomcat installed and working.

I have mod_jk installed, but don't think it's working.

Right now, if I go to the url it takes me to the apache success page, if I go to [url]/~[username] it loads whatever is in the user's directory, and if I go to [url]:8080 it give's tomcat page, and will execute java.

Can someone outline the steps I need to take in order to get this working? Give likely pitfalls? Or offer alternative ideas that let me accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mod_jk requires a minimal set of directives to signal Apache to send a request to a worker.

In particular, you should have a JkMount  directive. This tells Apache requests that match the URL defined in  to a particular worker configured at JkWorkersFile

I recommend the following for a simple example to get you started:

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html